# mssql Production DB server hitting 100% CPU

Tags: sql-server, cpu-usage

I have a mssql database server that infrequently hits 100% CPU usage. When this occurs no more connections can be made to the database.

The only solution we have had so far is to reboot the server. It does not occur using any type of frequency. Not at the same time, day anything. We went three weeks without anything happening, and so far its been a week since it happened the last time we experienced this problem.

When we review the SQL Server errors logs we can see a pid that appears to be causing the issue, but the logs dont store what the process was doing, was it being blocked by another process etc.

When the issue has occured we cannot connect to the box we cannot run any of the sp_who commands to try and identify what sql statement is being executed when the issue occurs. Will admit we are trying to connect using Management Studio.

We do not want to run SQL profiler, even on the DB box if we can avoid it because of the resource drain for what is happening so infrequently.

Am I missing a trick in that there something being recorded in the error logs, but because I am not a DBA, I am missing it.

Comment: Is the server a virtual server? Running in Hyper-V?

Comment: @Donal. The server is running within a VMWare virtual environment.

Comment: ok, we have seen issues with cpu spiking in SQL Server when hosted in a VM. This is typically because the standby RAM gets to large. We have to use RAMMap to empty the Working Sets. Not sure if it is the issue - but worth a try. See here: http://dandar3.blogspot.ie/2012/05/rammap-freeing-up-memory.html

Answer (score 1):

- There should statics shlould be updated.
- Index fragmentation should be check and reogarnize or rebuild sholud
  be done.
- Try search complete in covering indexes.
- Find out missing indexes and implemet.
- Remove unused indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do these things:

1. You may try to clear the cache using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`
2. You can [identify the most costly SQL Server queries using DMV’s](http://www.johnsansom.com/how-to-identify-the-most-costly-sql-server-queries-using-dmvs/)

   ```
   SELECT TOP 20
       qs.sql_handle,
       qs.execution_count,
       qs.total_worker_time AS Total_CPU,
       total_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
       qs.total_worker_time/1000000,
       average_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
       (qs.total_worker_time/1000000) / qs.execution_count,
       qs.total_elapsed_time,
       total_elapsed_time_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
       qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000,
       st.text,
       qp.query_plan
   FROM
       sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
       CROSS apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) AS qp
   ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC
   ```
3. You can check the Activity Monitor under Management and sort by CPU

Comment: R.T. when get in to work I will ask our infrastructure guys to run the query. As its production server I do not have access to it. Unfortunately when the issue occurs we are struggling to even remote onto the server, and as the instance will accept no more connections, we get timeout when attempting to connect error messages. So when the problem does occur, we cannot connect to the sql instance. In these instances the Activity monitor cannot help.

Comment: @DarrenGuy:- I can understand the scenario as I have been to this and for me the query resolved the purpose as I found that there was one query which was taking to much CPU usage and hence we had to kill the session of that particular user.

Comment: Try using the [Dedicated Administrator Connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) when normal connections don't succeed.  Not for day-to-day workloads, though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
check what is running in sql server and check cpu utilization of the spids or if any blockages are present.
**select * from sys.sysprocesses where spid>50 order by cpu desc;**
If you find any particular processes runs and cause CPU utilization then find out the tables and check last stats updated or any missing indexes for that table or perform index rebuild operation.
If server didint let you login or sql gets hang every time when CPU is high then Use data collection tool called **PSSDIAG** which is a diagnostic tool which will collect each and every action on the sql server so that you can later analyse the issue and its free and provided by Microsoft. Just run it for 10 to 15 min only because it'll take a lot space (depends on operations).